# Using the Contain Function in C#

Tags: c#, excel, stringbuilder

I am pulling in a excel file to my project everything was working fine but not I have grab all of the cell that contain WMI. I am having trouble with stbQuery does any one know the correct syntax for grabbing information that only contains certain characters.

```
OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection ("provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;data source=" + txtFileName.Text + ";Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;");

StringBuilder stbQuery = new StringBuilder();
stbQuery.Append("Select  [Wireless Number (uneditable)], [* Last Name] FROM [" + txtSheets.Text + "$] WHERE [* Last Name] = LIKE '%WMI%' ");
```

Comment: Have you tried taking out the `=`?  `WHERE [* Last Name] LIKE '%WMI%' `

Comment: I realize that this is a sample, but for others reading this later, you should remember to parameterize and/or sanitize data, even if it comes from a known spreadsheet. You want to capture errors in the source data as early as possible.

Comment: no but I just tried it and it worked thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an SQL Syntax - [LIKE](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp) Issue.

The `LIKE` Keyword doesn't need an `=` in Structured Query Language.

Example:

```
SELECT * FROM Customers
WHERE [* Last Name] LIKE 's%';
```

---

**UPDATE**

Look at *D Stanley* Comment.